# Java tab order: How to set Tab order in java swing table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am new to the java language and I want to set tab order in `JTable` in java swing.  How can we set tab order in java swing?

Comment: do you mean the columns of a JTable? Or which tabs do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the "FocusTraversalPolicy", not sure if that is easy to handle inside of a JTable, however here is the relevant article from Sun/Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

Answer (score 2):

http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.java.gui/Custom-Tab-order-within-a-JTable

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom Action that does tabbing the way you want. Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) to find out how to replace an existing Action.

Or for an example that reuses the existing Action to only tab to cells that are editable you can check out [Table Tabbing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/table-tabbing/).