# JTable Focus Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In a `JTable` when a tab key is pressed the focus is moved to the next cell of the of the table. Is there any way by which focus is moved down when tab is pressed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147713/java-tab-order-how-to-set-tab-order-in-java-swing-table/7148480#7148480

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as shown below. See also [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

```
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
InputMap map = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
map.put(tab, "selectNextRowCell");
```

Comment: good to know, because these codelines changed TAB from Horizontal to the Vertical +1