# Setting events for jtable cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am developing a project that requires using jtable to accept input to a database.

I want to set event listner for the cells in the jtable, any suggestions about What event to use for me to know When a user has finished editting a cell so that I can save the content of the cell and allow the user to move to next cell,

i have this code, but it is not working as i wanted, please you can help me look into it and tell me where i am making mistake

```
DefaultTableModel tablemodel;

/**
 * Creates new form Tabletest
 */
public Tabletest(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    SetTable();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jTable1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            jTable1KeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(72, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jTable1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    jTable1.getColumn(jTable1.getColumnName(jTable1.getSelectedColumn())).setCellEditor(new tablecell2()); // TODO add your handling code here:
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabletest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabletest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabletest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabletest.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Tabletest dialog = new Tabletest(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
// End of variables declaration

void SetTable(){
    try {
        tablemodel= new DefaultTableModel();
        tablemodel.addColumn("field1");
        tablemodel.addColumn("field2");
        tablemodel.addColumn("field3");
        tablemodel.addColumn("field4");

        Object[] a = {"10","20","30","40"};
        Object[] b = {"100","200","300","400"};
        tablemodel.addRow(a);
        tablemodel.addRow(b);
        jTable1.setModel(tablemodel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

void saveresult() {
    double tot = Double.parseDouble(jTable1.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), jTable1.getSelectedColumn()).toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, tot+ " the value will be save into db");

}

class tablecell2 extends JTextField implements TableCellEditor {

    int tablecell2_column;
    Object value;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, final Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.stopCellEditing();
        this.tablecell2_column = column;
        this.value = value;
        //this.setFont(null);
        System.out.println(">>tablecell2>>");
        if (value != null) {
            setText(value.toString());
        }

        this.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                jTextField1FocusLost(evt);
            }

            private void jTextField1FocusLost(FocusEvent evt) {
                //setText(value.toString());
                // new setResults().getbyclass(jTable1, ClassCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(), acadYr, term, subjectCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(currentCell, "focus");
            }
        });

        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(15, 20));
        this.setFont(new java.awt.Font("", 10, 9));
        //this.setFont(new java.awt.Font);
        /* this.addFocusListener(null);addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
         jTable1FocusLost(evt);
         }
         });*/
        this.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTextFieldMouseClicked(evt);
            }

            private void jTextFieldMouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
                setText("");
            }
        });
        this.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextField10KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
    }

    private void jTable1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "666");

    }

    private void jTextField10KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        int keycode = evt.getKeyCode();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("" + evt.getKeyChar());
        //jTextField10.setText(sb.toString());
        System.out.println("key code " + keycode);
        if (keycode == 10) {

            setText(this.getText());
            if (tablecell2_column == 3) {
                //Scores.CA_SCORE = Double.parseDouble(this.getText());
            } else if (tablecell2_column == 4) {
                //Scores.EXAM_SCORE = Double.parseDouble(this.getText());
            }
            //jTextField10.setText("");
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(currentCell, Scores.CA_SCORE);
            saveresult();
            this.nextFocus();
            //new setResults().getbyclass(jTable1, ClassCombo.getSelectedItem().toString(), acadYr, term, subjectCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

        }        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just for emphasis, already mentioned elsewhere: you **must not** act on the data in your editor, that's not its job. Its **only* job is to take to input and notify its listeners when editing is terminated, nothing else.

Comment: BTW: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

The table model will be called via the `setValueAt` method when a editing process has completed automatically.  Your table model should be overriding this method and storing the result of the editing process appropriately.

See [`TableModel#setValueAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) and [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: @nachokk I don't think so.  It's the responsibility of the editor to return a value.  It's the responsibility for the table model to store that value.  The `JTable` already acts as intermediary between these two, so what's the point?

Comment: just in the fly, a mix about the question i did to camickr, cause i don't like to validate in setValueAt i was thinking if exist another way like making your own editor and validating there(nothing to do with CellEditorListener)

Comment: @nachokk The model should still valid the incoming value, as you never know where it comes from, but I would agree with validating at the editor level where you can as well.  But this can be done in a number of ways that don't require you to attach editor listeners ;)

Comment: I Have used setCellEditor like this

Comment: jTable1.getColumn(jTable1.getColumnName(jTable1.getSelectedColumn())).setCellEditor(new tablecell2());

Comment: I created  the class tablecell2 implementing TableCellEditor, but When I clicked on cell without editting and clicked on the next cell to edit, the Values from the previous cell will be saved instead of the recent cell value

Comment: Show me some example code I can run.  It sounds like your table model isn't saving the values

Comment: the code is too long for this box, how can i get the code across to you?

Answer (score 1):

From the JDK API you can add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`.

Or you may want to consider the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/).

Comment: is a bad idea setting your own cell editor class for example with `jtextfield` and validate in this component ??

Answer (score 0):

thanks all i solved it with tableModelListener, here is the code

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.event.*;

import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableProcessing extends JFrame {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public JTable table =  new javax.swing.JTable();
private String[] columnNames = {"Item", "Quantity", "Price", "Cost"};
private Object[][] data = {
    {"Bread", new Integer(1), new Double(1.11), new Double(1.11)},
    {"Milk", new Integer(1), new Double(2.22), new Double(2.22)},
    {"Tea", new Integer(1), new Double(3.33), new Double(3.33)},
    {"Cofee", new Integer(1), new Double(4.44), new Double(4.44)}};
private TableModelListener tableModelListener;

public TableProcessing() {

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    table = new JTable(model) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override// Returning the Class of each column will allow different renderers
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) { // to be used based on Class
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }

        @Override //  The Cost is not editable
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);
            return (modelColumn == 3) ? false : true;
        }
    };
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188179/jtable-focus-query/7193023#7193023
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB, 0);
    InputMap map = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    map.put(tab, "selectNextRowCell");
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188179/jtable-focus-query/7193023#7193023
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    setTableModelListener();
}

private void setTableModelListener() {
    System.out.println("enter listen");
    tableModelListener = new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                System.out.println("Cell " + e.getFirstRow() + ", "
                        + e.getColumn() + " changed. The new value: "
                        + table.getModel().getValueAt(e.getFirstRow(),
                        e.getColumn()));
                int row = e.getFirstRow();
                int column = e.getColumn();
                if (column == 1 || column == 2) {
                    TableModel model = table.getModel();
                    int quantity = ((Integer) model.getValueAt(row, 1)).intValue();
                    double price = ((Double) model.getValueAt(row, 2)).doubleValue();
                    Double value = new Double(quantity * price);
                    model.setValueAt(value, row, 3);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(tableModelListener);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            TableProcessing frame = new TableProcessing();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: glad you solved your problem :-) just: don't  overrule its model decisions in a way that would widen model's constrants