# How to tab through components?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, focus

My `Swing` program has a lot of fields that the user has to fill in in order to make a query to a DB.

The problem is that when I press `tab` in one field, the focus is not moving anywhere at all.

All the info I read about the focus subsystem makes me think any program should do that by default, hence I'm asking, because my program doesn't do it.

I'm using `netbeans` and also tried setting nextFocusableComponent on the components but with no luck.

Any tips?

Comment: tabbing out off textfields should work without any tweaks (btw: better not use deprecated methods, strictly speaking there is no guarantee they will remain, though they will ... ) Let's see an sscce which demonstrates the problem

Comment: @kleopatra the problem is that my code is too big, i don't really know what to post so you can try to find where the problem is. And tabbing right now is just not working in any component at all.

Comment: something is wrong with your code and we can only help if we see it - **not** your complete code but an SSCCE which demonstrates the misbehaviour. It's your job to provide that SSCCE (often, you'll find the error yourself while preparing it :-)

Comment: do you use some 3rd prty control (apart from Swing's own)?

Comment: OK sounds dumb (as much as I am) but the problem was happening because I set the frame focusable property to false which makes me think that any component contained in it would lose the ability to be focusable.

Thanks all anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are other part of your code that could be causing you issues. But here is a reference from oracle that shows you how to set tab focuses and next focus. In this it also document other things you need to setup before it will work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html

I suggest you post portion of your code so other can see if there are other underlining issues.

Also there is another thread on stackoverflow about this issue: [Java tab order: How to set Tab order in java swing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147713/java-tab-order-how-to-set-tab-order-in-java-swing-table)

Comment: Copy/paste kleopatra's comment to Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the FocusTraversalPolicy class.

Hopefully this will help you: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FocusTraversalExample.htm

Comment: if the tab isn't recognized at all, a custom FTP doesn't help at all :-)

Comment: @kleopatra that's exactly the problem, all the FTP explain the order and whatnot but I don't have a problem with the order, my problem is that it just doesn't happens